# Unable to run The .NET Portability Analyzer on the Microsoft Windows Server 2016 (Datacenter)

Tags: asp.net, portability, .net-framework-version, windows-server-2016

I was assigned with the .NET Portability Analyzer scan on the Microsoft Windows Server 2016 (Datacenter)

On that datacenter we host ASP.NET Web Forms application hosted on the IIS version 10

I was told that I can download portable .NET Portability Analyzer from https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-apiport

I did download portable version and ran this command

```
C:\..\ApiPort.2.8.25.Offline\ApiPort.Offline\netcoreapp3.1\ApiPort.exe analyze -r DGML -f PROJECT_DIRECTORY
```

> I got this response
>
> You must install or update .NET to run this application.
>
> App:
> C:...\ApiPort.2.8.25.Offline\ApiPort.Offline\netcoreapp3.1\ApiPort.exe
> Architecture: x64 Framework: 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '3.1.32'
> (x64) .NET location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\
>
> The following frameworks were found:
> 8.0.1 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>
> Learn more: https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed
>
> To install missing framework, download:
> https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=3.1.32&arch=x64&rid=win-x64&os=win10

But I did install all the necessary frameworks, everything is up-to-date

Can some one suggest what is missing?

Comment: _"But I did install all the necessary frameworks"_ - have you installed the 3.1 version? Based on the error it needs not the latest but a specific one.

Comment: @GuruStron I did, I went to a site via the provided link and downloaded the 3.1 which did create a directory C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.32

Comment: What is the output of `dotnet --list-sdks`? Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: @GuruStron here is the output

8.0.101 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

I did reboot

Comment: Try `dotnet --list-runtimes` also.

Comment: @GuruStron here is the output

Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.32 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 8.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

Comment: Try downloading and installing the one for console apps from the linked page ([this one](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-3.1.32-windows-x64-installer)).

Comment: Also note that the provided tool seems to be phased out, consider looking into the Upgrade Assistant which also has a [CLI option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-overview?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website#upgrade-with-the-cli-tool).

Comment: Was glad to help! Adding as an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloand and install runtime for the console apps from the linked page ([this one](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-3.1.32-windows-x64-installer)).

Also note that the provided tool seems to be deprecated, consider looking into the Upgrade Assistant which also has a [CLI option.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-overview?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website#upgrade-with-the-cli-tool)